# Wine 1.4 and Office 2010 installation tutorial - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wine, documentation, microsoft-office

Since Wine 1.4, there is native support for Office 2010, but where is a good manual with the pre requirements?

Every time when I want to install Office 2010, the setup breaks up during the installation process and it says to me, "an error occured".

I have no idea, How can I see those errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try `playonLinux`.. Its a good front-end of wine and also support specific configuration for such application.

Comment: This isn't quite an answer to how to run Office 2010 in Wine 1.4, but provided you have a license for Windows, you could easily install VMware and run a copy of Windows for all the Windows programs that you depend on. This is how me and many others I know deal with this kind of situation. In fact, the best way is to have dual-boot with smaller Windows install and the rest for Ubuntu. Then while in Ubuntu - virtualize the existing Windows install under VMware. This way you have a) easy to access Windows env in Ubuntu; b) Bare-metal Windows env for all other cases.

Comment: I already did it with virtualizing, but the the notebook needs more energy and but it sucks to start every time the virtual maschine.
But thank you for you answer! :))
greetings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider viewing http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31 about the installer and searching various programs(Excel/Word/Publisher) [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true).  You should be able to install following these steps([from this page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336))

1. Run http://winetricks.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/install-gecko.sh by downloading, setting to executable permissions, and running in terminal.
2. Use the Wine config tool to create a new wine prefix somewhere where you will install. In this prefix, under DLL overrides, set `riched20` to the native version.
3. Before the installation, if your Ubuntu and Wine is 64-bit, add `export WINEARCH=win32` on a new line in `~/.profile`(It will be hidden, press Ctrl+H while viewing your home folder to see it)
4. Install as usual.

Unfortunately, the 64-bit version of Microsoft Office is reported to be garbage, while the 32-bit version ranks bronze, requiring installing `wine-mono` if it is not installed. Here are some of the 32-bit test results, paraphrased from the [WineHQ AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org):

- Excel: Silver, with some UI issues for objects over cells.
- Powerpoint: Gold, if you set `riched20` to native in step 2.
- Access: Bronze:

> Failures:Form and reports constructor can't save changes. Templates. Visual Basic. Most of macroses. UI elements with tables list.
>
> Word: Mixed results: some report garbage, while others state only charts and clipart don't work.